# Jquery Autocomplete - How to kill the input focus

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Question on Jquery Autocomplete.

loving the functionality, but theres was pesky problem, the script drops the cursor into the last autocomplete text field in my form thereby making the whole form shift down when the user loads the page... Can't find anywhere to kill this auto focus functionality.. any thoughts? help help.

Comment: Oops answered my own question in case someone else needs this. if you had 


`$("#seedcompany").focus().autocomplete(data,{multiple: true});`

you just need to remove the focus bit

`$("#yourdiv").autocomplete(data,{multiple: true});`

Comment: your right thanks for the feedback... it doesn't show up the JQuery  basic example but on the multiple examples this focus() call is sometimes used.